# MySQL UPDATE Based off of values

Tags: mysql

I need a query to update rows but first check if there a specific number.

```
Example: 
number = 10
```

If the row includes the number 10, don't update.
It needs to be just the query. Something like this.

```
SELECT `number` FROM `users`;
if row.number == 10 then don't update
else update set number=12
```

Comment: it seems level 0 question, not worth  of asking here

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE users
SET number = 12
WHERE number <> 10
```